# Header names as dates in r

Tags: r, time-series

I'm trying to calculate the "death" of users, meaning I want to determine the time duration between when a user signs up for a program and when they are no longer active in the program. I have two files which I read in using `read.csv("filename",header=TRUE)`:

```
 >   df
      name   start.date
1  Allison   2013-03-16
2   Andrew   2013-03-16
3     Carl   2013-03-16
4     Dora   2013-03-17
5   Hilary   2013-03-17
6    Louis   2013-03-19
7     Mary   2013-03-20
8   Mickey   2013-03-20
```

And file 2:

```
> df2
       names X04.16.2013 X04.17.2013 X04.18.2014  X04.19.2013
2001 Allison           5           5           0           0
2002  Andrew           0           0           0           0
2003    Carl           8           8           11          10
2004    Dora           6           4           9           3
2005  Hilary           2           0           0           0
2006   Louis           18         10           8           3
2007    Mary           4           7           7           0
2008  Mickey           9           5           0           0
```

What I would like to do is convert the header names of df2 to dates, so I can then create a new data frame that has the user names, start date, and "days to death", which would be when a user has an entry of 0 in df2:

```
      name   start.date   days.to.death
1  Allison   2013-03-16   33
2   Andrew   2013-03-16   0
3     Carl   2013-03-16   NA
4     Dora   2013-03-17   NA
5   Hilary   2013-03-17   31
6    Louis   2013-03-19   NA
7     Mary   2013-03-20   30
8   Mickey   2013-03-20   28
```

Note that Andrew was never "alive" and Carl, Dora, and Louis haven't "died" yet. I'm still rather new to R so any input is much appreciated!

Comment: is that a typo in the column headers of df2?  should they all be 2013?

Comment: My apologies. Yes, all dates in df2 should be of the year 2013

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming a typo in your column headers for df2, the following solution using dplyr and tidyr gets you most of the way there...

```
  library(tidyr)
  library(dplyr)

  colnames(df)<-c("names", "start") #  To join dfs, the first column header needs to be identical to df2
  df$start<-as.Date(df$start, format="%m/%d/%Y") #formatting date
```

The following works on df2 by long-forming the data, formatting the dates (similar to MrFlick's suggestion) and then only keeping the dates that have a 0 in them.   It then takes the first instance of this (i.e. the earliest date assuming your dates are in chronological order along the cols from left to right).   It then calculates the difference in date from that date (the enddate) to the start date from df.  I've used the same format as MrFlick - but you could simply calculate the difference as an integer.

```
  df2 %>% 
  filter(X04.16.2013!=0) %>%   #removes Andrew who has 0 in first date col
  gather(key,value,2:5) %>%     
  mutate(date=as.Date(key, format="X%m.%d.%Y")) %>%
  left_join(df) %>%
  filter(value==0) %>%
  group_by(names) %>%
  filter(date == nth(date, 1)) %>% 
  select(names, start, date) %>%
  mutate (daydiff=difftime(date,start, unit="days"))
```

gives this ...

```
    names      start       date daydiff
1  Hilary 2013-03-17 2013-04-17 31 days
2 Allison 2013-03-16 2013-04-18 33 days
3  Mickey 2013-03-20 2013-04-18 29 days
4    Mary 2013-03-20 2013-04-19 30 days
```

it should be pretty easy to put in the NAs and those who never lived.      Perhaps this helps a little?

Answer (score 1):

A simple `as.Date` with the right format will turn the column names into dates. First, a copy-pastable form of the data

```
df<-structure(list(name = structure(1:8, .Label = c("Allison", "Andrew", 
"Carl", "Dora", "Hilary", "Louis", "Mary", "Mickey"), class = "factor"), 
    start.date = structure(c(15780, 15780, 15780, 15781, 15781, 
    15783, 15784, 15784), class = "Date")), .Names = c("name", 
"start.date"), row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", 
"8"), class = "data.frame")

df2<-structure(list(names = structure(1:8, .Label = c("Allison", "Andrew", 
"Carl", "Dora", "Hilary", "Louis", "Mary", "Mickey"), class = "factor"), 
    X04.16.2013 = c(5L, 0L, 8L, 6L, 2L, 18L, 4L, 9L), X04.17.2013 = c(5L, 
    0L, 8L, 4L, 0L, 10L, 7L, 5L), X04.18.2014 = c(0L, 0L, 11L, 
    9L, 0L, 8L, 7L, 0L), X04.19.2013 = c(0L, 0L, 10L, 3L, 0L, 
    3L, 0L, 0L)), .Names = c("names", "X04.16.2013", "X04.17.2013", 
"X04.18.2014", "X04.19.2013"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("2001", 
"2002", "2003", "2004", "2005", "2006", "2007", "2008"))
```

And now

```
nn <- names(df2)[-1]
dts <- as.Date(nn, format="X%m.%d.%Y")
dts
# [1] "2013-04-16" "2013-04-17" "2014-04-18" "2013-04-19"
```

Then

```
lastedateid<-apply(df2[,-1], 1, function(x) {i<-which(x==0); ifelse(length(i), head(i,1), NA)})
lastdate <- dts[lastedateid]
lastdate
# [1] "2014-04-18" "2013-04-16" NA           NA           "2013-04-17"
# [6] NA           "2013-04-19" "2014-04-18"
```

and as long as `df$name==df2$names`

```
transform(df, days.to.death=difftime(lastdate,start.date, unit="days"))
```

will give the following assuming `start.date` is a proper `Date` class as well

```
     name start.date days.to.death
1 Allison 2013-03-16      398 days
2  Andrew 2013-03-16       31 days
3    Carl 2013-03-16       NA days
4    Dora 2013-03-17       NA days
5  Hilary 2013-03-17       31 days
6   Louis 2013-03-19       NA days
7    Mary 2013-03-20       30 days
8  Mickey 2013-03-20      394 days
```

Answer (score 0):

Following simple code may be useful:

```
names(df2)[1] = 'name'
merge(df, ddf2)
dfm$days.to.death = ifelse(dfm[,3]==0,0,ifelse(dfm[,4]==0,31, ifelse(dfm[,5]==0,33,ifelse(dfm[,6]==0,28,NA))))

dfm[,c(1,2,7)]
     name start.date days.to.death
1 Allison 2013-03-16            33
2  Andrew 2013-03-16             0
3    Carl 2013-03-16            NA
4    Dora 2013-03-17            NA
5  Hilary 2013-03-17            31
6   Louis 2013-03-19            NA
7    Mary 2013-03-20            28
8  Mickey 2013-03-20            33
```