# R: date was changed when I import from CSV file

Tags: r, csv, date, lubridate

I have a csv file which contains date such as "1/23/20 12:00".
I imported the csv file to R, the date was changed to "X1.23.20.12.00". 
I wanted this to convert date again and then tried

```
mutate(date=as_date(mdy_hm(date)))
```

by using lubridate package, but I couldn't manage that. 
It seems X makes problem.

Please tell me how to do this.

Comment: Try with `header = FALSE` while using `read.csv`.  It seemss that there was no header and it read the first row as header

Comment: But I need the first row to be column names...

Comment: @tantan - you need to give us a couple of example rows from your csv file to be sure, but I suspect you don't have headers if you are ending up with values starting with `X` and replacing `/` with `.` - see `make.names("1/23/20 12:00")` which is what R does when it is trying to make safe column names from data.

Comment: In addition to the above comments, if you are using something like `read.csv` review the `check.names` option...

Comment: possible solution in this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25496424/header-names-as-dates-in-r

Comment: tanks all, now I got it. First I need "header = FALSE" and then change the colnames.